# Property 'users_index' does not exist on type 'typeof UserApiController' when trying to access static method in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am brand new to TypeScript, and trying to call a function on a class.

In file A:

```
import userAPIController from "./controllers/customer/userAPIController";

userAPIController.users_index();
```

In file B:

```
export default class UserApiController {

    public users_index(): void {
        User.findAll({
            attributes: ["given_name", "family_name"]
        }).success(function (users: any) {
            console.log(users);
        });
}
```

I get the error:

```
Property 'users_index' does not exist on type 'typeof UserApiController'
```

I've also tried to add an interface:

```
interface userAPIController {
    users_index: any;
}
```

With no luck.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a simple documentation issue

Answer (score 0):

`UsersApiController` is a class, so you'll need to instantiate it before you can call its methods:

```ts
const controller = new usersApiController();
controller.users_index();
```

You can read more about using classes here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: Is there no way to call a static method?

Comment: If the method is static, yes. You'd have to define it as `static users_index(...) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

The function you've written isn't a isn't a static method, it's an instance method. If you want it to be static, change it to:

```
static users_index = (): void => {
 // content omitted
}
```

For more on static properties, [see this page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#static-properties)

Or if it's correct that it's an instance method, use the `new` operator to create an instance before you try to access it:

```
const controller = new UserApiController();
controller.users_index();
```

Comment: Oh, doh, thanks. I didn't see that in the docs when I was googling for how to call a static method in TypeScript. My apologies.